# Determine the currently executing statement in a long running PL/pgSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, monitoring

I have a long running PL/pgSQL stored procedure in PostgreSQL. How can I determine the currently executing statement in it?

Comment: If you are able to instrument the function and restart it, you could add a `RAISE LOG` or `RAISE NOTICE` command to emit whatever you like. I can't think of any way to determine the currently-executing query of a function other than that.

Comment: I've long wanted to be able to get a "stack" of calls via `pg_stat_activity`, but neither I nor anybody else have wanted it enough to actually implement it. We really should add something where you can send the back-end a signal and get it to dump a call-stack, though.

Comment: Actually, [it looks like Pavel cared enough to add something close](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRChsM1zshEFi0Sy6_VHQpWQ6gr0o6d3qvt9tGG9ovnNNA@mail.gmail.com) and [it got committed into 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20130724232318.GL15510@tamriel.snowman.net). It isn't non-intrusive like you want, though, I don't think you can invoke it from outside a pl/pgsql function. The Pl/PgSQL debugger might be able to do this, but you'd have to have loaded it first...

Comment: A colleague also found https://github.com/johto/call_graph and pointed it out to me. Again, not quite what you're after unfortunately, as it cannot be used by signalling the running process while it's in the call.

Comment: @CraigRinger - some simply tool can be written with PLpgSQL plugin API. A most difficult part is only signal handling probably.

Answer (score 4):

One *crude* but effective method, available in any version, is to [raise notices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) in your plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
PERFORM ...
RAISE NOTICE 'step1';

INSERT ...
RAISE NOTICE 'step2';

DELETE ...
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Another possibility would be to use [auto-explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) with

```
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON;
```

The second method gives you a lot more than you asked for. Both are crutches and work-arounds and more or less *intrusive*.
The upcoming feature in **9.4** by Pavel that [@Craig identified](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56689/determine-the-currently-executing-statement-in-a-long-running-pl-pgsql-stored-pr#comment102106_56689) in his comment seems like a major improvement:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS text_var = PG_CONTEXT;
```

It's already [documented in the /devel manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-GET-DIAGNOSTICS-CONTEXT).